# Extracting text locations from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, text, position, pdfbox

I'm trying to find location of text elements in PDF. I've extended PDFTextStripper for this purpose. I'm using [multi-page LaTeX-produced PDF](http://www.wave.org.au/jupgrade/images/sample.pdf) for testing.

```
public class TextFinder extends PDFTextStripper {
    private static final Logger logger =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(TextFinder.class);

    private PDRectangle mediaBox;

    public static class CMProcessor extends OperatorProcessor {

        @Override
        public void process(PDFOperator operator, List<COSBase> arguments)
                throws IOException {

            if ("cm".equals(operator.getOperation())) {
                logger.debug("CM operation");
            }
        }
    }

    private CMProcessor cmProcessor = new CMProcessor();

    public TextFinder() throws IOException {
        this.registerOperatorProcessor("cm", cmProcessor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startPage(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        super.startPage(page);
        mediaBox = page.findMediaBox();
        logger.debug(String.format("MEDIA (%f,%f) (%f,%f)",
            mediaBox.getLowerLeftX(), mediaBox.getLowerLeftY(),
            mediaBox.getUpperRightX(), mediaBox.getUpperRightY()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)
            throws IOException {
        for (TextPosition position : textPositions) {
            float x = position.getXDirAdj();
            float y = mediaBox.getHeight() - position.getYDirAdj();
            logger.debug(String.format("(%f,%f) (%f,%f)", x, y,
                x + position.getWidthDirAdj(), y + position.getHeightDir()));
        }
        super.writeString(text, textPositions);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that all positions seems to be translated such a way that (0, 0) is the coordinates of the leftmost topmost text element:

```
MEDIA (0.000000,0.000000) (595.270020,841.890015)
(0.000000,0.000000) (11.486961,14.255401)
(11.486961,0.000000) (20.660002,14.255401)
(20.660002,0.000000) (36.733482,14.255401)
```

Thanks to mkl, the problem is caused by custom OperatorProcessor. Without it it works just fine. But I need operator processor, because I use it for finding images. Still I don't quite understand, why adding custom processor affects behavior of PDFTextStripper.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue. Running your code, though, I get different coordinates, especially not starting at 0,0. Which PDFBox version do you use? I tested using 1.8.8. If I remember correctly, there used to be a version in which `writeString` retrieved a buggy `textPositions` list.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't add custom OperatorProcessor to the snippet, which is actually causing this problem.

Comment: *Still I don't quite understand, why adding custom processor affects behavior of PDFTextStripper.* - actually you don't add but instead replace the existing one, and the transformation matrix is very important in the context of determining positions.

Comment: I made the comment an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why adding custom processor affects behavior of PDFTextStripper.

The reason is that your *adding*

```
registerOperatorProcessor("cm", cmProcessor);
```

actually *replaces* the existing Processor. The original one was important for determining the correct position on page.

The solution is to chain processors.

Comment: I've solved this problem by overriding `PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFOperator operator, List<COSBase> arguments)` instead of using `OperatorProcessor`.

Comment: That essentially is chaining, too. You merely chain processOperator calls instead of Processor.process calls.